# Where, when and why use functions?

Tags: function, syntax, logic

It might be a matter of preference, and thus be biased. But it's such an important matter that I find it really interesting to have some feedback on this question.

Needless to say, any language needs them. But when and why is it best to resort on them?

- Is it wise to use a function just for clarity, even if it's not used more than once in the code?
- Where do you usually declare your functions (in js for instance), just before you use them for the first time? at the beginning of the script? …?

Comment: #1 yes #2 in the beginning is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice we use at our company is to only use functions when a piece of code is reused, were the function is located depends on what is reusing the function.  If it is only used, lets say within a class then we would keep the function within that scope. If is it reused by other classes then most likely we would add it to a utility class accessible by other classes unless it is directly associated with that class object in that case we would make it public within that class.

Hope that helps!